# MySQL Replication of INSERT... SELECT with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, replication, sql-order-by, insert-select

The [documentation page for INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) states that for `INSERT ... SELECT` to work with replication, an `ORDER BY` some column must be used so that rows may be inserted in a predictable order, therefore auto-increment columns will function correctly.

This has me wondering... when you do an `ORDER BY` and the column you pick is non-unique, what does MySQL use to decide further ordering?  It must be deterministic, otherwise the documentation would say that you need to choose an `ORDER BY` unique column, yes?  Or is the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an ORDER BY with a column which does not have distinct values for all matched rows, the order is nondeterminstic, yes.

This does break statement-based replication, IF the inserted order matters. The inserted order certainly matters if you use an auto_increment column in the destination table, but often doesn't otherwise.

Order also matters if you have a LIMIT on the statement (update and delete too).

However, if you use row-based replicaiton you can do pretty much anything you like and not break replication. At least, not unless you really try.

---

These rules are so complicated, that I recommend that you just ALWAYS use a completely determinstic ORDER BY on an insert... select, or an UPDATE with a LIMIT.

Row-based replication is also your friend. I've not really used it much in production, but understand that

- It is more similar to how replication works in other databases
- Most of the time it Just Works.